# Oracle SQL : Regexp_substr

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have below sample values in a column

```
Abc-123-xyz
Def-456-uvw
Ghi-879-rst-123
Jkl-abc
```

Expected output is the third element split by '-', in case there is no third element, the last element will be retrieve.

See expected output below:

```
Xyz
Uvw
Rst
Abc
```

Thanks ahead for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code and data samples with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: its not regex_substr in your question title, oracle have regexp_substr

Comment: Thank you all for the edit. will improve next in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT initcap(nvl(regexp_substr(word, '[^-]+', 1,3),regexp_substr(word, '[^-]+', 1,2)))  FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach:

```
SQL> with t1(col) as(
  2    select 'Abc-123-xyz'     from dual union all
  3    select 'Def-456-uvw'     from dual union all
  4    select 'Ghi-879-rst-123' from dual union all
  5    select 'Jkl-Abc'         from dual
  6  )
  7  select regexp_substr( col
  8                      , '[^-]+'
  9                      , 1
 10                      , case
 11                           when regexp_count(col, '[^-]+') >= 3
 12                           then 3
 13                           else regexp_count(col, '[^-]+')
 14                        end
 15                      ) as res
 16    from t1
 17  ;
```

Result:

```
RES
---------------
xyz
uvw
rst
Abc
```

Comment: Just to note that REGEXP_COUNT() was only introduced in 11g (the other regex functions were available in 10g)

Answer (score 2):

```
regexp_substr(column, '(.*?-){0,2}([^-]+)', 1, 1, '', 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it without RegEx:

```
with t1 as(
  select 'Abc-123-xyz' as MyText     from dual union all
  select 'Def-456-uvw'     from dual union all
  select 'Ghi-879-rst-123' from dual union all
  select 'Jkl-Abc'         from dual
)
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(t1.mytext, LENGTH(t1.mytext) - INSTR(REVERSE(t1.mytext), '-') + 2) 
FROM t1
;
```

Comment: ^ true, my fault, I thought he always wanted to get the last triple of characters...